# proof of $\mathrm{arg}(1+\frac{z}{n})=\mathrm{Im}(\frac{z}{n})+o(\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, approximation

I'm looking for the proof of the following statement:$$\mathrm{arg}(1+\frac{z}{n})=\mathrm{Im}(\frac{z}{n})+o(\frac{1}{n}).$$

I found it on page 108 of Arnold's『Ordinary Differential Equations(1973)』, though it is not apparently related to differential equations.

Here is my attempt at a proof.

Since $n\cdot \rm{arg(\it{w}\rm)}=\rm{arg(\it{w}^n\rm)}\pmod{2\pi}$ and $\rm{arg(\it e^z\rm)}=\rm{Im}(\it z\rm)\pmod{2\pi},$

$$n[\mathrm{arg}(1+\frac{z}{n})-\mathrm{Im}(\frac{z}{n})]$$
$$=\mathrm{arg}\{{(1+\frac{z}{n})}^n\}-\mathrm{Im}(z)\pmod{2\pi}$$
$$=\mathrm{arg}\{{(1+\frac{z}{n})}^n\}-\mathrm{arg}(e^z\rm)\pmod{2\pi}$$
$$=\mathrm{arg}\{(1+\frac{z}{n})^n/e^z\}\pmod{2\pi}.$$
But $(1+\frac{z}{n})^n/e^z \to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, so $n[\mathrm{arg}(1+\frac{z}{n})-\mathrm{Im}(\frac{z}{n})]\to2k\pi$ as $n \to \infty$, for some integer k.

Therefore
$$\mathrm{arg}(1+\frac{z}{n})=\mathrm{Im}(\frac{z}{n})+\frac{2k\pi}{n}+o(\frac{1}{n}).$$

How can I verify, if my argument is correct, that $k=0$?

Comment: It's not correct. You can't deduce that the limit is $2k\pi$ for some integer $k$ from what you wrote

Comment: I see. Then what would be an appropriate proof for the equality?

Comment: *I've edited the 4th line from below to clarify my proof attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem of coping with "modulo $2\pi$", but a *limit problem*.

Assume that $z=x+iy$ is given and fixed. Then
$${\rm Re}\left(1+{z\over n}\right)\geq1-{|z|\over n}>0$$
as soon as $n>|z|$, which we shall assume from now on. Then
$${\rm arg}\left(1+{z\over n}\right)={\rm arg}\left(1+{x+iy\over n}\right)=\arctan{{y\over n}\over 1+{x\over n}}$$
and therefore
$${\rm arg}\left(1+{z\over n}\right)-{y\over n}=\arctan{y\over n+x}-{y\over n}=:a_n\ .$$
It remains to show that  $a_n=\,o\bigl({1\over n}\bigr)$ when $n\to\infty$. Now $\arctan t=t+o(t)$ when $t\to0$. It follows that
$$a_n={y\over n+x}+o\left({y\over n+x}\right)-{y\over n}={-xy\over n(n+x)}+o\left({y\over n+x}\right)=o\left({1\over n}\right)\qquad(n\to\infty)\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\mathrm{arg}\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)=\mathrm{arg}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}+i\frac{y}{n}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{\frac yn}{1+\frac xn}\right)=\frac y n + o\left(\frac1n\right)=$$$$=\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{z}{n}\right) + o\left(\frac1n\right)$$

indeed by binomial expansion

$$\frac{\frac yn}{1+\frac xn}=\frac yn\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-1}=\frac yn\left(1-\frac xn+ o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=\frac yn+ o\left(\frac1n\right)$$

and recall that as $x\to 0$ we have $\arctan x=x+o(x)$.

Comment: How do you justify the third $\>=\>$ in your reasoning?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter By binomial expansion for the denominator! I add this step. Thanks